# adjusted R2 of training dataset is not constant

Tags: r, regression, training-data

I split my entire dataset into two parts: one for training and the other for testint.

The training dataset contains 70 observations and the test dataset contains 14 observations. 
My model has 1 numeric dependent variable and 5 numeric independent variables.

I run multiple regression with my training dataset, and every time I run the code for the regression, the value of the adjusted R2 in training dataset was not constant but it continuously changed. Its values varied from 60% to 70%.

The function that I used for the data split, contained "sample" and "set.seed" function in its code.

My question is... in this case, how do I interpret the non constant values of adjusted R2 from training dataset? Is it normal?

```
splitdf <- function(dataframe, seed=NULL) {
   if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
   index <- 1:nrow(dataframe)
   trainindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/6))
   testset <- dataframe[trainindex, ]
   trainset <- dataframe[-trainindex, ]
   list(trainset=trainset,testset=testset)
}

splits <- splitdf(df, seed=1234)
str(splits)
my_train <- splits$trainset
my_test <- splits$testset
```

PS: the model well satisfied with all the linear regression assumptions.

Comment: If you are using random sample, I don't understand why you expect R2 to be constant.

Comment: Please post a code sample. If you `set.seed` at the beginning of your code and call `sample` twice, they will give you two different splits. To get the same random split, you would need to call `set.seed` with the same seed before the second split.

Comment: Quantum mechanics at work and play.

Comment: hi Metrics,nice to meet you. i just want to know whether it is ok to have such wide range of adjusted R2(in my case the adjR2 varies from 60% to 70%).. is it normal? thanks for your comments..

Comment: hi josilber... i posted the code.. thanks..

Comment: @JacobGreen given that you have a tiny dataset I'm not surprised you see significant variability in the quality of your fit based on the random training/test split. However, SO is not the correct place to ask about whether this degree of variability is unusual -- a better place would be crossvalidated.com, a website that specializes in statistics. SO is better for specific programming questions (e.g. "why does this code not work").

Answer (score 0):

If you use same seed your R2 should not be changing.

```
#sim data
set.seed(12)
data <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(10),X1=rnorm(10),X2=rnorm(10),X3=rnorm(10))

#split data
splits <- splitdf(data, seed=1234)
my_train <- splits$trainset
my_test <- splits$testset
summary(lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,my_train))$r.squared
#[1] 0.3922881

#split again using same seed...get same results
splits <- splitdf(data, seed=1234)
my_train <- splits$trainset
my_test <- splits$testset
summary(lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,my_train))$r.squared
#[1] 0.3922881

#split using different seed...get different results
splits <- splitdf(data, seed=5555)
my_train <- splits$trainset
my_test <- splits$testset
summary(lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,my_train))$r.squared
#[1] 0.7948203
```

Comment: thanks Benjamin.. just one more question.. after setting seed NULL, is it normal to have the range of adjusted R2 varies from 60% to 70%??

Comment: if you set seed to null you will get a different training set each time and so your R2 shouldn't be the same. How much it varies will depend on your data and I wouldn't be able to answer that